# change the color of the link of the same menu in another page when you click on a link of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to change the color of the link of the same menu in another page when you click on a link of a page ?

Here is the menu in the home page, the help page and in the contact page :

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/help">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

/* Before visited link */

```
nav ul li a {
  color: #000;
}
```

/* After */

```
nav ul li a:visited {
  color: #00ff78;
}
```

all links in the visited menu are the same color, but I want the active link only change color.

Comment: The problem with visited is that'll be applied to every link (once you've visited that page). You need to add an `active` class to each item based on the URL.

Comment: What do you mean with "the same menu in another page". Are you asking to change the color of the menu-item on _the new page_ after it is clicked on the previous page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
}

/* selected link */
nav ul li a:active {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz try this code..

**JQUERY**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('click','nav a',function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('.active').removeClass();
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
a.active {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
nav ul li a {
  color: #000;
}
nav ul li a:active{
  color: #00ff78;
}
```

You need to use active if you only want the link of the current page, visited will trigger permanently on any link previously used.

Answer (score 0):

If I click on Home, the home menu will be activated in all other pages

The same for the help and contact pages